# View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE has no effect

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

On Ice cream sandwhich and jelly bean I want to lower the profile of the status bar for my game.

```
    if(Integer.parseInt(VERSION.SDK) >= 14)
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

I call this, but there is no effect made to the status bar. I suppose I am missing something but after looking over the docs and google for quite some time I can't find anything. My device is a Nexus 7. Here's is snippet of my manifest if it helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find SDK is deprecated you need SDK_INT http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK also chuck a log statement in your if statement's body to make sure it's getting executed.